# Access Virtual Host with port via network in Mac XAMPP

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I Want to create a virtual host in my XAMPP with 8001 port number. And this should be accessible via my private network. 
For Example: 192.168.1.2:8001 
How can I do that?
Here is my Vhost code

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName 192.168.1.2
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dir"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dir">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add the proper Listen directive in server config context `Listen 192.168.1.2:8001` for example

Comment: Thanks ezra-s.. Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added `Listen 192.168.1.2:8001` to my `httpd.conf` file. And Its working..